# Am I abusing the idea of log levels here?

Tags: java, logging, exception, slf4j

I have a case where I want to introduce some error logging. But at this point I'm not sure how often exceptions will occur here (experimental feature, errors dependent on user input) and I'm a bit worried about flooding the logs with stacktraces.

So I came up with this solution:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception during save()", ex); // log with stacktrace
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("Exception during save(): {}", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

But I'm not really satisfied with this because I feel like abusing the debug level for logging on error level. I use `org.slf4j.Logger`.

Comment: It's not "abuse" - actually I find it quite clever. Fact is: It still _is_ an error, just you want to have a little more verbose logs when in Debug. So if that is your intention, then this is exactly what your code does. Legit, IMHO.

Comment: What kind of Logger do you use?

Comment: It's org.slf4j.Logger

Comment: I'm not familiar with slf4j, but doesn't that let you specify the format for exceptions, including whether or not you want to include the stack trace? If it does, that sounds like a better way to configure this behavior. If not, this feels like a reasonable workaround to me.

Comment: Another option might be to have two loggers - one "detailed" and one "brief" - those could presumably be configured and enabled separately.

Comment: @Fildor: That won't compile as-is, as there's no conversion between `String` and `Exception` in either direction. If there's an `error` method with a second parameter of type `Object` then casting either `ex` or `ex.toString()` to `Object` would work, but you would need the cast. If the OP actually wants to call different overloads, then using the conditional operator won't work here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, I'm spoiled ... you are right. Confused it with another logging framework.

Comment: Depending on the actual Logger implementation (logback?) you could also use Filters to Filter out any verbose output when not in debug or higher. But Jon's approach will probably have better performance.

Comment: Just a thought: isn't it better to have the stack trace always? The error should not be so frequent that this is a problem. In case it happens you have all information already and don't have to reproduce the situation with debug logging enabled.

Comment: @Henry Agreed for production code. But OP says it is an "experimental feature" - so I think the concern about unintentionally flooding the logs is reasonable. But: Maybe an alternative could be to set up a "dead time" if it is just a single place of (possible) error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about not spamming the logs with irrelevant stacktraces, you can still kind of not abuse the idea of log levels but embrace it instead :

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  LOGGER.error("Exception during save(): {}", ex.toString()); 
  LOGGER.debug("Detailed exception output:", ex);
}
```

Performance-wise your proposed solution using `isDebugEnabled` scores a little bit better, as the String object (first argument) won't get created for the second call unless you really need it. And you also spare a single level on the call stack.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - and logging twice is bad, because... ? Op didn't say anything about (arguable, edge-case) performance, his concern were the stacktraces. Also this logs twice only in the event of an actual exception happening *and* the log level being set to debug or more detailed, so I'd argue that this is a not a big tradeoff after all.